# Acessar funções dentro de classes no kivy + python

Tags: python, kivy

Esse é o arquivo .py

```py
class Tela():
    pass
class teste():
    def chama(self):
        pass
    def save_d(self):
        pass
    
class Prg(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tela()
    
Prg().run()
```

Esse é o arquivo .kv

```
<Tela>:
    Button:
        on_release: O qu colocar aqui para acessar a função chama()
```

Comment: Apresente um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.

Comment: Pronto, editei.

Answer (score 1):

Com o prefixo app dá para aceder a métodos da classe principal.

prg.kv

```
<Tela>:
    Button:
        on_release: app.teste.chama()
```

Prg.py

```
class Tela(Widget):
    pass
class teste():
    def chama(self):
        print("chama")
        pass
    def save_d(self):
        pass

class Prg(App):
    def build(self):
        self.teste = teste()
        return Tela()

Prg().run()
```

Comment: Entendi, eu editei  a perguntei e queria saber, caso eu precise acessar outra classe, por exemplo uma classe Teste1()

eu tentei on_release: app.teste1.chama() não deu certo. Queria entender como acessar várias classes. Valeu

Comment: as novas classes têm que estar definidas na classe Prg